# Extract list of images selected by lassotool

Tags: python, extract, bokeh

I have a dataframe df, like this [x,y,image_list], and I am creating a 2D scatter plot of x, y points. Now I want to extract a list of only those images selected by lassoselect tool. I have tried many things but nothing is working.

Code block for reference

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import LassoSelectTool, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.events import SelectionGeometry
import pandas as pd
import glob

folder_path = "C:\\Users\\User_name\\img_folder_path"
image_list = glob.glob(f"{folder_path}/*.jpg", recursive=True) + glob.glob(f"{folder_path}/*.png", recursive=True)

data = {
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'y': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    'image_list': image_list[:10]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

# Create a scatter plot
p = figure(width=400, height=400, tools='lasso_select', title='Image')
scatter = p.scatter('x', 'y', source=source)

#JavaScript callback
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    const selected_indices = source.selected.indices;
    const selected_image_list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < selected_indices.length; i++) {
        selected_image_list.push(source.data['image_list'][selected_indices[i]]);
    }
    // Send the selected image URLs to the Python code
    console.log("Selected Images:", selected_image_list);
""")

#JavaScript callback to the scatter plot's data source
scatter.data_source.selected.js_on_change('indices', callback)

show(p)
```

I have tried JS callback function to print these images on console. But nothing works, Any help would be appreciated

BTW here is a link to same question on bokeh community. "https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/extract-list-of-images-selected-by-lassotool/10772?u=sidddhartha_kosti"

Comment: you are using JS callback, that means it is printed in your browser console, and that is the case here, in case you need to something more with python here, I suggest you use python callbacks with bokeh server

Comment: Thanks Aritesh for reply.  BTW, is there any other way to resolve this issue. As I am planning to use this code block on streamlit

Comment: What do you need to do with getting selection back in Python. Once its a standalone object, there is no python kernel

Comment: Hey Aritesh, I have a list of around 1000 images, and I only want to show those images selected by LassoSelectTool in my streamlit ui. This is what I want to achieve